# How can I get the number of keys in an .ini file using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, parsing, ini

Is there any way to get the number of keys from an .ini file?

ie.
[mysection]

```
server=192.168.1.100
port=1606
blah1=9090
temp1=abcd
```

etc

I want to get number of key (from the above example it should return 4)

Please, any help will be great.

Comment: How are you parsing the INI file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel32.dll exports GetPrivateProfileSection() which returns a null-separated list of name/value pairs.  You can count the pairs.